How to remove the $\forall$ rules of inference in natural deduction?
Some proofs in logic become easier by reducing our set of logical symbols e.g. by using $\forall x \phi$ as an abbreviation for $\neg\exists x \neg \phi$. If we were to do this, what would happen to the $\forall$ inference rules in natural deduction? The options seem to be:

We could remove them, as they follow from the $\exists$ rules of inference.
We must keep at least one of them while expressing it in terms of $\exists$ as opposed to $\forall$.

My naive guess is that $(2)$ is true, as the $\forall$ rules of inference allow us to write sentences with free variables such as $(x + 0 = x)$, which are needed in many proofs.

Yes, if you introduce $\forall$ as an abbreviation for $\lnot \exists \lnot$, you can prove the universal quantifier rules using those for the existential one. Simple exercise.

But the original system has a rule that allows us to go from $\forall x.\phi(x)$ to $\phi(c)$. If we remove this, can we infer $\phi(c)$ from $\lnot\exists x.\lnot\phi(x)$ ? I don't think so. $\lnot\exists\lnot$ is intuitionistically weaker than $\forall$.

@MJD yes, Classically we can derive $\phi(c)$ from $\neg \exists x \neg \phi (x)$ since $\neg \phi (c) \to \exists x \neg \phi (x)$ is valid, and we have contraposition.

When I wrote that comment, I had temporarily forgotten that classical logic existed!

It's option 1: if you completely remove $\forall$ from your language, then obviously any rules involving $\forall$ don't do any work.  But the remaining system is still both expressively and derivationally complete.
